# How to save extracted zip file with specific filename

Tags: php, zip

I have zip files with only one file inside it, but it has new name every time. I need to extract file and save it with **specific file name**, not extracted one.

```
  $zip = new ZipArchive;
  $res = $zip->open($tmp_name);
  if ($res === TRUE) {

   $path = _PATH."/files/";
   $zip->extractTo($path);
   $zip->close();
   echo 'Unzip!';
  }
```

Abowe code works, but I need to have specific filename. For example anyfile located under zip (eg. **pricelist025.xml** should be named **temp.xml**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rename your specific file before you extract it.

```
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$res = $zip->open($tmp_name);

if ($res === TRUE) {       
    $zip->renameName('pricelist025.xml','temp.xml');
    $path = _PATH."/files/";
    $zip->extractTo($path);
    $zip->close();
    echo 'Unzip!';
    } else {
             echo 'failed, code:' . $res;
       }
```

I hope this works.
**UPDATE 1**

There is two options if you want to change the file names.
1. change the file names before extracting -*This way zip files will be modified*
2. change the file names after extracting -*Zip files will remain as they were before*

**Changing file names before extracting**

*We have to define a pattern for filenames.* 
Here, Files will be in this patter : `myfile0.xml, myfile1.html, adn so on..` 
*Note: extension will be preserved.*

```
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$res = $zip->open('hello.zip');

$newfilename = 'myfile';
for($i=0;$i<$zip->count();$i++)
{ 
   $extension = pathinfo($zip->getNameIndex($i))['extension'];
   $zip->renameName($zip->getNameIndex($i), $newfilename.$i.'.'.$extension);

 }
```

**Chaning file names after extracting**

*File names will in the same pattern as above.*

```
$directory = 'hello/'; //your extracted directory
$newfilename = 'myfile';

foreach (glob($directory."*.*") as $index=>$filename) {

      $basename = pathinfo($filename)['basename'];


      if(!preg_match('/myfile\d\./', $basename)) {

                $extension = pathinfo($filename)['extension'];

                rename($filename,$newfilename.$index.'.'.$extension);
                }
      }
```

What we are here scanning the all the files from the extracted directory for which doesn't have a filename in the patter `myfile[num].` and then we are changing it's name.

**UPDATE 2**

I just noticed you have updated your question.
As you have just one file and you want to extract it every time with different name. 
*You should rename it every time you extract.*

```
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$newfilename = "myfile".rand(1,999); //you can define any safe pattern here that suites you

if($zip->open('help.zip')===TRUE)
{
    $path = '/your/path/to/directory';

    $filename = $zip->getNameIndex(0);


    if($zip->extractTo($path))
    {
        echo "Extracted";
     }else{
           echo "Extraction Failed";
        exit();
     }

     $extension = pathinfo($filename)['extension'];

     rename($path."/$filename",$path."/$newfilename".'.'.$extension);

     echo "Extracted with different name successfully!";

  } else {  
        echo "Failed";
  }
```

Comment: Not working because I do not know will given name be 'pricelist025.xml'. I've put that just as example. I do not know the name of file inside upfront.